# ModelSim Register is illegal error

Tags: compiler-errors, verilog, modelsim

So i am getting the error

## ** Error: C:/Modeltech_pe_edu_10.3c/examples/HW6/alu.v(53): Register is illegal in left-hand side of continuous assignment

for the assign statement [assign result = 32'd0;] any ideas why? i have tried moving that cluster of statements all around the code and the only way it works is if i completely remove the part of the code.

Issue there is that i need that to run my test bench. Any ideas on what this error means and how to solve it?

```
//
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    module alu
    (
        //--------------------------
        // Input Ports
        //--------------------------
            input   [31:0]  operand0, 
        input   [31:0]  operand1, 
        input   [3:0]   control,
        //--------------------------
        // Output Ports
        //--------------------------
            output reg  [31:0]  result,
        output          zero,
        output      overflow



    );
        //--------------------------
        // Bidirectional Ports
        //--------------------------
        // < Enter Bidirectional Ports in Alphabetical Order >
        // None

        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // Begin Design
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


            assign  result  = 32'd0;
        assign zero     = 1'b1;
        assign overflow = 1'b0;




    always @(*)


    begin
    case(control)




    4'b0000: result = operand0 && operand1;

    4'b0001: result = operand0 || operand1;

    4'b0010: result = operand0 ^ operand1;

    4'b0011: result = !(operand0 || operand1);

    4'b0100: result = operand0 + operand1;

    4'b0110: result = operand0 - operand1;

    4'b1000: result = operand0 < operand1;

    4'b1001: result = operand0 << operand1;

    4'b1010: result = operand0 >> operand1;

    4'b1011: result = operand0 >>> operand1;
    endcase

    end



    endmodule
```

Answer (score 0):

First: a type `reg` cannot be assigned in an `assign` statement; it is a rule of Verilog. "Register is illegal in left-hand side of continuous assignment" mean a register can not be assigned by a `assign` statement. left-hand side as in left of the `=`.

Second: Even if a type `reg` could be assigned in an `assign` statement, you will have multiple drivers on `result` as it is being assigned in the always block. `assign` statements are continuous drivers, meaning it will always be applying a value to the signal no matter other blocks are doing to the same signal. If there are any conflicts (ex one applies 1 and the other applies 0) the result will be `'bx`;

Solution: Remove the line: `assign result = 32'd0;` `result` is combinational logic and does not need an initial value.